# Select last n rows without use of order by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I want to fetch the last n rows from a table in a Postgres database. I don't want to use an `ORDER BY` clause as I want to have a generic query. Anyone has any suggestions?

A single query will be appreciated as I don't want to use `FETCH` cursor of Postgres.

Comment: "Without use of order by" is logical nonsense. In a query without `ORDER BY`, the order is undefined and there are no "last" rows. You probably mean "without the use of `LIMIT`".

Comment: Hi Erwin, if I don't want to use order by, it means I want the last added n rows. And the solution given by Lukas gives me that result.Database also maintains the order in which the rows are inserted (which is said a natural order) and I wanted such last n rows.

Comment: This is unreliable. There is no "natural order" in an RDBMS by definition. I have more to write than what a comment will hold, please see my answer.

Comment: @mitalpritmani: Erwin is right. You *shouldn't* assume that you will reliably get the last n rows in the physical table. You might at least want to consider ordering by `oid` or even better, by your own primary key. Then, of course, the whole question is obsolete, as you can `ORDER BY oid DESC LIMIT :n`...

Comment: As a side note, the OID column is not added to user tables anymore (since 9.0 if I'm correct.) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-oid.html

Comment: OP asks about tables, but If you consider functions such as `ts_debug` that return records in a certain order, but don't provide a column to do `order by desc` on - then this is a valid and useful question.

Answer (score 10):

That you get what you expect with Lukas' solution (as of Nov. 1st, 2011) is **pure luck**. There is **no "natural order"** in an RDBMS by definition. You depend on implementation details that could change with a new release without notice. Or a dump / restore could change that order. It can even change *out of the blue* when db statistics change and the query planner chooses a different plan that leads to a different order of rows.

The **proper way** to get the "last n" rows is to have a timestamp or sequence column and `ORDER BY` that column. Every RDBMS you can think of has `ORDER BY`, so this is as 'generic' as it gets.

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

> If `ORDER BY` is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the
> system finds fastest to produce.

Lukas' solution is fine to avoid `LIMIT`, which is implemented differently in various RDBMS (for instance, SQL Server uses `TOP n` instead of `LIMIT`), but you **need** `ORDER BY` in any case.

Comment: Hey Erwin, thanks for your information. I think I had missed these points. I read the manual and came to know about this point which you have quoted here. So does this mean that I can't have last inserted rows from database and I will always have to use order by? Please give me answers to these questions.

Comment: @mitalpritmani: Yes, that't what it means. If you want the "last n rows" reliably, you **have to** `ORDER BY` (thereby specifying, what "last" means exactly). Everything else is pure luck. If you don't have columns to identify the "last" rows, you'll have to add something like a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html).

Answer (score 6):

Use window functions!

```
select t2.* from (
  select t1.*, row_number() over() as r, count(*) over() as c
  from (
    -- your generic select here
  ) t1
) t2
where t2.r + :n > t2.c
```

In the above example, `t2.r` is the row number of every row, `t2.c` is the total records in your generic select. And `:n` will be the n last rows that you want to fetch. This also works when you sort your generic select.

**EDIT**: A bit less generic from my previous example:

```
select * from (
  select my_table.*, row_number() over() as r, count(*) over() as c
  from my_table
  -- optionally, you could sort your select here
  -- order by my_table.a, my_table.b
) t
where t.r + :n > t.c
```

Comment: Hey Lukas, your previous answer was easy to understand, I mean with both queries. Can you please put that also as an example so that I can accept your answer? And ya, this query should be starting with "select t2.* from(select t1.*, .....)" so please correct it. If I write t1 first and then t2, it gives me error - missing FROM-clause entry for table "t2".

Comment: @mitalpritmani: You're right, I got a syntax error there... Corrected, and restored my previous example

Comment: @LukasEder: This answer is misleading in that it supports the superstition of the OP he could rely on a natural order without `ORDER BY`. See my answer about that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Good point. I was assuming, though, that the OP is aware of that. That's why I said that my solution is generic in a way that it can deliver the last n rows of any query, no matter how sorting is applied

Comment: And since the order is unknown, the _last N records_ is semantically equivalent to _the first N records_, or _any N records_.