# Compute a running ratio of two totals

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, aggregate-filter

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4.1 database (Retrosheet data) with a table `events` containing one row per baseball play. I want to a compute a running batting average for a given player: the formula is (total number of hits so far)/(total number of valid at-bats so far).

I can use window functions to get a running total of hits for David Ortiz, whose player code is `ortid001`, using the following query:

```sql
SELECT count(*) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
FROM events WHERE bat_id='ortid001' AND (event_cd='20' OR event_cd='21' 
OR event_cd='22' OR event_cd='23');
```

(The clause involving `event_cd` just identifies which rows are considered hits.)

Using the same technique, I can get a running total of at-bats (the `event_cd` clause rejects every row that doesn't count as an at-bat. note that the hits selected above are a subset of at-bats):

```sql
SELECT count(*) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
FROM events WHERE bat_id='ortid001' AND (event_cd != '11' AND 
event_cd!='14' AND event_cd!='15' AND event_cd!='16' AND     
event_cd!='17');
```

How can I combine these? Ideally, for each row describing a play with `bat_id='some_player_id'`, I would compute two functions: the count of all preceding rows describing an at-bat, and the count of all preceding rows describing hits. Dividing these gives the running batting average at that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (since it hasn't been declared) `event_cd` is data type `integer` and can be NULL.

```
SELECT *, round(hit::numeric / at_bat, 2) AS rate
FROM  (
   SELECT input_ts
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE event_cd = ANY ('{20,21,22,23}'::int[]))
                   OVER (ORDER BY input_ts) AS hit
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT (event_cd = ANY ('{11,14,15,16,17}'::int[]))) 
                   OVER (ORDER BY input_ts) AS at_bat
   FROM   events
   WHERE  bat_id = 'ortid001'
   ) sub
ORDER  BY input_ts;
```

Since you are using pg 9.4, you can use the new aggregate `FILTER` clause. Related answer:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

The frame definition `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default, so you don't have to declare it.

But there is no "natural order" in a database table. Don't confuse this with a spreadsheet. You *need* to define it with `ORDER BY`. I am using the imaginary column `input_ts`, replace it with a (list of) column(s) that defines your sort order. More:

- [Select last n rows without use of order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950641/select-last-n-rows-without-use-of-order-by-clause/7966628#7966628)

I avoid `NOT IN`, because it exhibits tricky behavior with NULL values.

The cast to `numeric` is to avoid integer division which would cut off fractional digits and lead to questionable usefulness. Rounding the result to two fractional digits.

Comment: Thanks; is there a way to explicitly order by primary key? Or is this just as bad as relying on the current default ordering?

Comment: @MichaelCurry: Sure, just put the name(s) of PK column(s) there. Good / bad is a function of your requirements. The "default" ordering without `ORDER BY` is just an arbitrary order that can change any time. It's how Postgres can render the rows in the most convenient way, typically the current physical order of rows on disk, which often coincides with the order that rows were inserted. But that can change any time, with `VACUUM` or `CLUSTER` or any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation.  You haven't specified the `order by` clause, which is what you really need for the window function.  The query you want is something like:

```
SELECT sum(case when event_cd in ('20', '21', '22', '23') then 1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY ??),
       sum(case when event_cd not in ('11', '14', '15', '16', '17') then 1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY ??),
       (sum(case when event_cd in ('20', '21', '22', '23') then 1.0 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY ??) /
        sum(case when event_cd not in ('11', '14', '15', '16', '17') then 1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY ??)
       ) as ratio 
FROM events
WHERE bat_id = 'ortid001';
```

Put the appropriate ordering column in for `??`.

Comment: in this case, the rows in the database happen to already be in the correct order. So the OVER clause is just `OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. This gives correct results but I'm not sure if there's a preferable way to do this.

Comment: There is no such thing as a table being "in the correct order".  Tables represent unordered sets.