# filter the data from records in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a one table. in which, there are 12 records available. in those i want to filter and get data like from hp cell value  source column  to before hp cell value source column records.

Here is the table :

```
seq_id       file_name      source       date

b21345350    a.txt          ad          2022-04-15
b32145660    e.txt          qe          2022-04-15
c43526890    ace.txt        hp          2022-04-15
re2345566    wer.csv        hp          2022-04-15
b43251044    op.xlsx        fa          2022-04-15
b6512400     ip.csv         jm          2022-04-15
b9123420     tb.xlsx        tp          2022-04-15
b3214563     cv.txt         ux          2022-04-14
b45678900    em.txt         hp          2022-04-14
b65357023    rt.csv         hp          2022-04-14
b90879081    ty.txt         mp          2022-04-14
b19019019    sd.txt         jp          2022-04-14
```

Here it should be output result :

```
 seq_id       file_name      source       date

c43526890    ace.txt        hp          2022-04-15
re2345566    wer.csv        hp          2022-04-15
b43251044    op.xlsx        fa          2022-04-15
b6512400     ip.csv         jm          2022-04-15
b9123420     tb.xlsx        tp          2022-04-15
b3214563     cv.txt         ux          2022-04-14
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify the criteria you're using to select the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no natural order of rows in a relational database (like there is in a spreadsheet). See:

- [Select last n rows without use of order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950641/select-last-n-rows-without-use-of-order-by-clause/7966628#7966628)
- [Deterministic sort order for window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114882/deterministic-sort-order-for-window-functions/31117079#31117079)

Assuming an `id` column to establish the order of rows that you seem to take for granted (and is *not*), this would work:

```sql
SELECT (t).*
FROM  (
   SELECT t, count(*) FILTER (WHERE source = 'hp') OVER (ORDER BY id) AS hp_ct
   FROM tbl t
   ) sub
WHERE hp_ct BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c55cb7c77d7f14fef0f334601cb8232)*

You seem to want all rows starting with the first instance of `source = 'hp'` and stopping at the 3rd instance of the same. So do a running count in the subquery `sub`, and then filter all rows with count 1 & 2.

I work with a table alias `t` to grab the whole row and decompose in the outer `SELECT` to get rid of the added `hp_ct` without spelling out all column names. That's optional.

Comment: I am getting error like : SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 53.  i am using dbeaver tool with postgres

Comment: I don't have the id column in table. Is it possible to use date column?

Comment: @learnthings: My statement is correct, as can be seen in the fiddle. dbeaver is rather limited. Try psql instead. May also be a *very* old version of Postgres - always disclose your version! Any (set of) columns is *possible* that defines an unambiguous order of rows. The `date` column in your example does not do that. Fix your question to provide proper information to work with.

Comment: Whatever the answer you provided that is correct. But additionally you added the id column. so i don't need that id column. is there any possible chance to get the same resultai thou the using Id column.

Comment: @learnthings: Like I said: any (set of) column(s) that establishes your desired order of rows can replace id ... Measure of last resort: `ctid`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117079/939860